# OpenAI API error: "The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated"

Tags: php, openai-api, gpt-3

I was using the ChatGPT and it says to use this line of code for the API endpoint:

```
$endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions';
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
{ "error": { "message": "The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated, learn more here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations", "type": "invalid_request_error", "param": null, "code": "model_not_found" } }
```

I can't really find anything to fix it.

I tried changing the models in the URL itself but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you check the link in the error ? From what I can see, they provide replacements. Have you tried any of them ?

Comment: I did but It didn't work when I tried it

Comment: What's the error message you get when you are trying the alternative ? "it did not work" is not enough information to help you with anything. Please refer to the [ask] section before asking.

Answer (score 17):

There are two problems with your code.

## 1. You're trying to use a deprecated OpenAI model

On January 4, 2024, OpenAI [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations) a lot of models.

See the deprecated models and recommended replacements in the tables below.

In your case, change `text-davinci-003` for `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct`.

##### Instruct GPT models

| SHUTDOWN DATE | LEGACY MODEL | RECOMMENDED REPLACEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-ada-001` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-babbage-001` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-curie-001` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-davinci-001` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-davinci-002` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-davinci-003` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |

##### Base GPT models

| SHUTDOWN DATE | LEGACY MODEL | RECOMMENDED REPLACEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-04 | `ada` | `babbage-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `babbage` | `babbage-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `curie` | `davinci-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `davinci` | `davinci-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-davinci-002` | `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` |

##### Fine-tuning GPT models

| SHUTDOWN DATE | LEGACY MODEL | RECOMMENDED REPLACEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-04 | `ada` | `babbage-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `babbage` | `babbage-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `curie` | `davinci-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `davinci` | `davinci-002`, `gpt-3.5-turbo`, `gpt-4` |

##### Edit models

| SHUTDOWN DATE | MODEL | RECOMMENDED REPLACEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-davinci-edit-001` | `gpt-4` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-davinci-edit-001` | `gpt-4` |

##### Embedding models

| SHUTDOWN DATE | LEGACY MODEL | RECOMMENDED REPLACEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-similarity-ada-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-ada-doc-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-ada-query-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-search-ada-code-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-search-ada-text-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-similarity-babbage-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-babbage-doc-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-babbage-query-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-search-babbage-code-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `code-search-babbage-text-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-similarity-curie-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-curie-doc-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-curie-query-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-similarity-davinci-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-davinci-doc-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| 2024-01-04 | `text-search-davinci-query-001` | `text-embedding-ada-002` |

## 2. You're trying to use a deprecated OpenAI API endpoint

All Engines API endpoints were [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) a very, very long time ago.

Change this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```